# How to understand German when listening to a native German person?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm learning German on [Duolingo](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/duolingo-language-lessons/id570060128) also watching [Learn German](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaeT58uDMlPpBlwAYaxN0LA) on YouTube, and I've completed the 1st phase (the basics). There are probably 6-7 phases of total in the app. But I don't wanted to depend on Duolingo or Learn German, so I decided to read and watch some of the actual German "sites" and "videos".

Now the problem is I don't understand anything apart from `UND` `DANKE` `NEIN` when I listen to those native German conversation. I know that I have just finished the basics and there are a lot more things to cover, but I just wanted to be sure I'm going in the right direction.

I'd like to get tips about how to understand the German conversations really fast (like in real time).

Thanks...

Comment: There’s no shortcut to acquiring vocabulary; you actually have to acquire the vocabulary. (The flipside is, listening and reading will, in the long term, help you acquire the vocabulary.)

Comment: Come on, learning a language takes several years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a good time starting exposing yourself to native speakers (or writers) is after about three or four years of learning a language in school. That is when schools begin exchange programs, and that is when schools begin to introduce reading matter that wasn't specifically written for language learners.

There are immigrants who don't speak the language of their new home country and learn it from the people they work with, so you can of course expose yourself to a language without any basic knowledge, but learning a language that way is much easier when you yourself are a part of the context and the speakers speak to you, adapting their behavior and their speech to your ability.

For example, when a native speaker interacts with a person he knows doesn't speak the language well, they will speak more slowly and form shorter sentences or even use single words. They will also accompany their communication with gestures, such as pointing to the object they talk about or miming the activity their refer to. And they will wait for a sign of understanding and repeat or rephrase what they said, if they weren't understood.

A book or movie doesn't do any of that for you. At your level of learning, if you are impatient and have more time to learn, it might be a better idea to:

- learn faster, i.e. learn more words per day, do more lessons
- repeat more often (to cement your knowledge even better)
- use different courses in parallel (they all have different approaches and different materials, so you will get both more repetition and more stable "mental storage" from the variation in exercises)
- use audio, video, and reading materials that are specifically created for learners at your level (publishers of language courses for schools often publish a wide variety of accompanying exercises, stories, and other material)

When you know a bit more, a good way to learn spoken German is watching German language movies with subtitles, either in your language or, if you are more advanced, in German.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with [the other answer by @user10239](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/5110/50) in that I think you can dive right into listening comprehension immediately, and I would strongly recommend doing so. There is no need to wait 3-4 years, and I would argue that doing so is actually inefficient and even dangerous, i.e. making it so that you develop a lot of bad habits that you will spend years having to "unlearn".

I have seen so many students who pour 3-4 years of classroom learning into German or another language, and yet have barely any speaking or listening comprehension in real-world settings. In many senses, they haven't even been learning real German, they've been learning an artificial classroom representation of it, and as such they struggle to connect their "book learning" with actual real-world usage.

There are several different mental skills that you need to develop in order to be able to understand spoken German with ease.

The first is for your brain to process the phonology of the language, i.e. you need to hear the basic building blocks or phonemes, including vowels and consonants.

German has considerable overlap with English, but there are important differences. The hardest vowel sounds to most speakers of standard American English are the long and short `ö` and the long and short `ü`. Most of the other vowels are close enough to English vowels that you will usually hear them as distinct without much additional effort. Because English does not have `ö` or `ü`, however, your brain may initially "gloss over" these vowels, instead perceiving them as the same as `o` and `u`, or perhaps occasionally mishearing them as other vowels in some contexts.

In terms of consonants, the hardest ones for most English speakers are the two `ch` sounds (there are two subtly different ones, summed up in the sentence "Ich auch.", the `ch` in "ich" is more in the front of the mouth whereas in "auch" it is farther back) and the `r`. Keep in mind there are two separate `r` sounds in German, the "swallowed" one at the end of words, like "der", and the clearly-pronounced one, in words like "rot". Germans also have several different ways of pronouncing the `r`, which vary regionally, so you need to make sure you are perceiving all of them. Lastly, one more sound I'd focus on is the soft `g` on the end of words.

Other sounds are unique to German, but usually English speakers have little trouble with them, such as `Pf` as in "Pferde".

I have found that practicing my pronunciation, by playing German words over and over again, pronounced by native speakers, listening closely to them, and trying to match them, helps a lot. The listening is the key here. [Forvo](https://forvo.com/) is your friend; you can look up any word on it.

Why is mastering the phonology so important? A lot of the "inaccuracies" of mishearing sounds are things where you can get away with a poor match if you're listening to someone speaking slowly, clearly, and loudly. But make someone start talking quickly, quietly, in a regional accent, or introduce background noise into the scenario, and it becomes more difficult, and your chance of listening errors (either mishearing words, or just not knowing what you're hearing) increases hugely.

When you've mastered the basics of the phonology of the language, good enough that you hear the phonemes accurately when the language is spoken quickly, it will be *much easier* for you to start connecting your "book learning" of vocabulary and grammar with things you hear real native speakers saying, whether in actual conversations with them, or just in watching videos or listening to audio in the language. And you'll find that you have better "error correction", like you can better process fast speech, understand a wider range of regional accents, and even hear someone in a noisy room.

Once you've gotten to this point, the way to get better is just exposure, time, and effort. Watch videos that you're interested in. Try to converse face-to-face with native speakers as much as possible. If you can't do it in-person, find a language partner. Tons of Germans want to learn English and Germany is well-connected online, and relatively few English speakers learn German, so it's pretty easy to find partners even though there are fewer German speakers globally than English speakers.

Over time you can work on vocabulary, grammar, word choice, and all of the other "higher-level" structural aspects of a language. I find that a solid mastery of the phonology makes it much easier to pursue all of these things, mainly because it becomes easier to connect "book knowledge" that you can get from a classroom, from tools like Duolingo, Lingvist, or Clozemaster, or from online tutorials or articles, with real-world listening comprehension (and hopefully, speaking ability.)

Answer (score 2):

Cazort is right on. This is how I learned Spanish. With German I am ready to listen to it at normal speed no subtitles just audio and try to be patient while gradually I make out words and phrases I am learning in books etc.

Yes it's a matter of sustaining close attention to the sounds in spite of not really getting whole chunks one might well get by reading. Yes hear the phonemes. I try to hear those chs but also the abundant z and ts sounds (the letter s drpending on where it is, the german z (a ts I think),the hard ge and the en sounds and of course the innumerable sch (sh)s. The ens seem to stand out.

Maybe it really is more like learning English (though as a native I wouldn't know) in that you should listen more for consonants rather than vowels as you do with the Romance languages. But yes listen for those umlauts. I'm confident sense will begin to emerge if give this approach enough time and effort. Jim

Comment: I want to add something though. Before I started this "just listen" exercise I studied German - English dictionaries. Wrote my own simplified one. Runs to about 15000 words. I also studied the Grammar. Also reading bilingual versions of classics. All that said, comprehending German as spoken with no dumbing down or slowing down is proving difficult. I will not pretend otherwise. A tool I may go back to is the "langsam gesprechen Nachrichten" you can find on DW. The "slowly spoken news" with the text at hand in German and English